# Android - why is the IMarketBillingService file an iadl file and not .java

Tags: android

I am just curious, but for Android billing, Android provides this class:

```
import android.os.Bundle;

interface IMarketBillingService {
    /** Given the arguments in bundle form, returns a bundle for results. */
    Bundle sendBillingRequest(in Bundle bundle);
}
```

but the extension of it is not .java but .iadl  ...why is that? :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's like a contract between the service and your app for allow communication between them.

You can get more details here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html